# A General Strategy for Images with Captions in Content

Tags: 7, media, nodes

This is a 'general direction' topic. I'm looking for some strategy and philosophical guidance, before marching over to the module development forum at Drupal.org.

I'm new to Drupal, and am very impressed by the architecture - the flexibility and power of the framework as a whole.

However, like many 'newcomers', I've quickly discovered that there's some planning and investment required in creating a new Drupal site (which is apparently the subject of many debates that are shaping the future of Drupal itself - http://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-8-where-drupal-and-where-...).

At the moment, for me at least, there's only one piece missing, and that's a non-Javascript method for allowing content creators (site owners) to insert one or more images with captions into the content of a node (like a news article, or blog post).

I also understand that in terms of semantic purity, it would be nice if the content of a node was clean and tidy, without a lot of additional markup - and so I'm looking for an eloquent way to solve the image/caption problem.

I poured over several other solutions - although as a new poster here I can only share two links in this post :(

and...

http://purewebmedia.biz/articles/2013-01-10/how-insert-and-float-inline-... - which is a great write-up describing the difference between using an Image field (with custom locations/folders for image stores), vs. Media Manager - although it doesn't address the caption problem.

I've also read a little about the new Entity model in DR7 - and I'm beginning to wonder of File Entities, with some kind of token replacement might be the right approach? (although I confess I don't entirely understand yet if a token can be placed into the free text/content field of a node - like the main text of an article or news story).

What I'm looking for is a method that will allow a user to insert one or more images into the content area of any content type (article, basic page, whatever - assuming the field/function has been defined for the content type), and that when they upload and insert that image, they are allowed to enter additional information like a title, copyright, caption, date etc.

They should be able to 'see' the image in their WYSIWYG editor (although maybe not the metadata), and then when the node is published, the required metadata is retrieved and inserted via a hook, pre-processor - for example, by surrounding the image in a div, and placing the required metadata above or below the image (perhaps in additional divs or elements) - requiring only CSS to style the title, caption, etc. as required.

I also really like Image Styles feature of Drupal and so I'm wondering how this could all be brought together.

To be clear, this is not a gallery module. The requirement here is to be able to insert one or more images with captions (and possibly other metadata fields) into a the content/body or a story, news article, blog post etc.; needing only CSS to style the result (format caption, float left or right etc.)

Thoughts?

Any pointers on how to start with this?

Comment: Why not using http://drupal.org/project/insert with http://drupal.org/project/jcaption ?

Answer (score 2):

Your desire for a "non-Javascript" solution is in conflict with your desire to allow users to "see" the image in their WYSIWYG editor, as you need to run Javascript for those to work.  So, you'll have to either drop the "non-Javascript" requirement, or be satisfied with image fields that may appear above or below the main body.  [Note 1: Images "above" the node body can be set to float left or float right, and thereby appear to be inside the text.  Note 2: If by "non-Javascript" you mean non-JS at render time, then no problem.]

Whichever way you go -- be it images embedded in a WYSIWYG editor, or images as file fields, you'll probably want to use the [media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module, as it can support either method.

There is a lot of information available on the media module, which is becoming "the way" to do images in Drupal.  Many additional contrib modules are compatible with media. You'll want to take a look at the following two configuration guides:

[Media 2.0 Quickstart](http://drupal.org/node/1699054)

[Configuring embedded images with media and wysiwyg modules](http://drupal.org/node/1882314)

Here is the point where I remember to take a step back and point out that my experience is with media 2.0-unstable7.  Depending on how comfortable you are with making adjustments to php code, you might prefer to use the stable release, which is currently 7.x-1.2.  I didn't have too much trouble with 2.0-unstable7, except for the fact that it does not support editing of arbitrary image metadata on WYSIWYG images, so I am using only image file fields at the moment.  If the only metadata you wish to attach to your images is a caption, then I expect that 7.x-1.2 should work for you, although I have not tried it myself.

In any event, I would recommend using the provided "title" field, and render that as a caption. Doing that is as easy as visiting admin/structure/file-types and clicking on "manage display" for the image file type.  This page works just like the "manage display" page in cck; you can just drag the "title" field up so that it is under the "file" field, and use css to style it as a caption.  You'll probably also want to download and enable the [entity_view_mode](http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) module, which will allow you to define additional view modes for your image files.

As I said, I'm not embedding images in WYSIWYG editors at the moment, but the article you quoted gives good advice on that.  If you're using the media module, you should still be able to format the title field as a caption regardless of whether you're using file fields or WYSIWYG.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - although to clarify - I was referring to a non-JavaScript implementation on the front-end. I've seen some solutions which depend on jQuery, for adding elements below an image as well as using the alt or title attribute of the image etc. for the caption. What I want is final markup in the browser - and I'm beginning to think that maybe a token filter might be one part of the solution. I'll also take a closer look at media module, file-types display and entity_view_mode as you've suggested.

Comment: This is pretty much how we are handling images with caption and credits, but we add separate field for each and then render as needed.

Comment: Okay I've read - and tried this... http://drupal.org/node/1699054 - it works, and so does using the Media manager button on the WYSIWYG editor. However, so close - and yet so far. The image is wrapped in a div, and a nested div contains the caption. However, right-clicking on the image in the editor window, and aligning-left - floats the image, not the enclosing DIV. What I really want is a div that's set to the width of the image, with a caption below that, and the whole thing floated left or right.

Comment: Can't help you with the float issue; I tried using WYSIWYG, but like MPD, I needed to add fields to my images, and had to give up on WYSIWYG (for now) because I didn't know enough jQuery to solve http://drupal.org/node/835516. If I may make a suggestion, though -- your question above is quite large. If you asked about WYSIWYG + Media w/ captions float in a new brief and focused question. Then perhaps someone who can help with that specific aspect of this very broad subject might see it and give you a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - using the new File Entity module, the new Media module (2.x) and the new Entity view modes module (http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) - along with the basic instructions here... http://drupal.org/node/1699054 - it's possible to create custom Entity view modes for left, center, or right aligned images, along with matching CSS classes, and image styles.

Here's the result.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. I infer from context that you gave up on using the standard wysiwyg float control & just went with setting the view mode in the media browser dialog. That seems best.

Comment: Here's a link the complete write-up on the steps I took to achieve this...
http://www.58bits.com/blog/2013/03/06/how-to-add-captions-to-images-in-drupal

Answer (score 0):

I too do not understand why most, if not all image caption modules require JavaScript. Scripting is fine for dynamic content. Here it just adds unnecessary complexity.

Drupal natively offer a filtering feature allowing to edit the HTML code content on-the-fly on server-side before it is delivered to the client. IMO this is the most natural place to turn image's title into caption, and it is even very easy to do!

1. Create a module in which you will define two functions as the ones shown below:

   ```
   /**
    * Implements hook_filter_info().
    * Add a new text filter implementing images captions.
    */
   function my_module_filter_info() {
     $filters = array();
     $filters['image_caption'] = array(
       'title' => t('Display image title as caption'),
       'process callback' => 'filter_image_caption_callback',
     );    
     return $filters;
   }

   /**
    * Callback for my_module_filter_info().
    * Takes a content text as input, edit all <IMG> tags and reuse the  `title'
    * parameter as caption.
    */
   function filter_image_caption_callback($text, $filter, $format, $langcode, $cache, $cache_id) {
     $text = preg_replace(
       '%<img ([^>]*(?:(style="[^"]+")[^>]*)?title="([^"]+)"[^>]*(?:(style="[^"]+")[^>]*)?)/?>(?:</img>)?%iU',
       '<div class="image" $2$4><img $1/><div class="caption">$3</div></div>',
       $text       
     );    
     return $text;
   }
   ```

   These functions will add a new text filter labeled "*Display image title as caption.*" which will take the content images' `title` attribute to generate the captions.

   The image and caption become encapsulated in CSS-styleable `<DIV>` containers, the outer-most inheriting the original `<IMG>` tag style (`float` attribute, etc.).

   You may want to personalize the produced `<DIV>` tag classes, or maybe replace them with the HTML5 `<FIGURE>` and `<FIGCAPTION>` tags.
2. Refresh your Drupal cache to take these new function into account,
3. Go in ***Configuration > Texts formats*** to edit your text format,
4. Add the newly created text filter:

   - *After* any other filter which could generate `<IMG>` tags needing captions,
   - *Before* any security and file structure checking filter.